# Does the C++ standard guarantee that std::string::resize(new_size) will not cause allocation if the new_size is not greater than the old one?

Tags: c++, string, performance, memory-management, standards

```
#include <string>
#include <cassert>

int main()
{
    auto s = "hello"s;
    auto p = &s[0];

    s.resize(3);
    assert('h' == *p); // always ok?
}
```

**Does the C++ standard guarantee that `std::string::resize(new_size)` will not cause allocation if the `new_size` is not greater than the old one?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note first that standards normally set requirements rather than guarantees.

`std::basic_string::resize` is not required to not reallocate the string if `resize` argument is less than its current `size()`. In fact, the C++17 standard says that the current string is replaced by a new string:

> If `n <= size()`, the function replaces the string designated by `*this` with a string of length `n`
> whose elements are a copy of the initial elements of the original string designated by `*this`.

When small string optimization is used, resizing to a smaller size may cause the string to store the characters in-place, rather than in a dynamically allocated buffer.

---

In C++20 standard `resize` is made `constexpr` and the above wording is gone, see [string.capacity](http://eel.is/c++draft/string.capacity#5.1):

> `constexpr void resize(size_type n, charT c);`
>
> 5 #Effects: Alters the value of `*this` as follows:
>
> (5.1) If `n <= size()`, erases the last `size() - n` elements.
>
> (5.2) If `n > size()`, appends `n - size()` copies of `c`.

Answer (score 4):

It does not guarantee validity of pointers:

> References, pointers, and iterators referring to the elements of a basic_­string sequence may be invalidated by the following uses of that basic_­string object:
>
> - Passing as an argument to any standard library function taking a reference to non-const basic_­string as an argument.
> - Calling non-const member functions, except operator[], at, data, front, back, begin, rbegin, end, and rend.

`resize` is a non const member function and is not in the list of member functions guaranteed to not invalidate references.